# overflow flag and conditional jump

Tags: assembly, arm, overflow

In slide , 15 of [this](http://simplemachines.it/doc/arm_inst.pdf) document contains that ,

> 1100 = GT - Z clear, and either N set and
>               V set, or N clear and V **set** (>)

in ARM assembly language. I had spend several hours trying to realize this.
first the result should be positive, or positive overflowed value.
Then shouldn't it be corrected into,

Either , V is set and N is set or V is clear and N is also clear.

I have done flowing readings on this topic already, but could not
understand why this should be like this.
http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt

The ISA is ARM (Advanced Risc Machine ) however the explanation of overflow flag
is global among all computing universe right? Could you please review the above 
stated text and tell me is that wrong? if right please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right, the pdf is wrong. It's obviously self-contradicting. The `GE` and the `GT` cases should only differ by checking the `Z` flag. For `GE` it has `N set and V set, or N clear and V clear` (and that's correct), so `GT` should be the same with the added check for `Z=0`.

Comment: Look at his question.  That `GT` is `GE` with the additional `Z` clear, meaning `Z=0`.  The PDF is ok.

Comment: @artlessnoise: it's not ok, because it says `N clear and V set`

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed the last **set** and filled in the details by speed reading. You are right.

Comment: Oky so I'm going to accept this answer and email the author of that article. Referring this question that I shoot on stackexchange.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the ARM ARM (arm architectural reference manual) found at infocenter.arm.com, just get the ARMv5 one if in doubt.

```
GE, signed greater than or equal, N==V
GT, signed greater than N==V and Z==0
```